# How to remove deep properties using Immutable

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have the following object as an Immutable Map:

```
{
  "email": {
    "events": {},
    "value": "test@mail.com"
  },
  "name": {
    "events": {},
    "value": "My Name"
  }
}
```

Using Immutable, how can I remove the `events` property for all objects? Something like (pseudo-code):

```
fields.deleteIn(['*', 'events'])
```

Alternatively (bonus question), it might be better to just filter so that only `value` is preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

```
fields = fields.map(field => ({ value: field.get('value') }))
```

**UPDATE: 12/7/2016**

Actually, that's kind of lazy and doesn't really remove the field obviously. This is better:

```
fields = fields.map(field => field.delete('events'))
```